# How do I connect iPhone to local Python client over Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm running a basic Python client over Bluetooth:

```
import bluetooth

bd_addr = "78:A3:E4:07:14:27"

port = 1

sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((bd_addr, port))

sock.send("hello!!")
sock.close()
```

I'd like to connect to the client using CoreBluetooth and my iPhone as the server pushing data, but I'm unsure how. The end goal is to transfer text from the iphone to the Python server, and have it print the data.

EDIT****
the documentation doesn't offer much help on using non-objective c devices. for example, I'm not sure if I need to advertise, because that seems like an iOS thing, whereas python only deals with the sockets. how would i interface between the two?

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) yet? Do you have a specific issue or are you looking for a tutorial?

Comment: When I ran the above code, my iPhone said " Macbook Pro is trying to connect..." but then said connection is unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to initiate a Bluetooth connection with an iOS app using that code. That code is using a Bluetooth 2.1 profile which is only supported with MFi devices on iOS.  Core Bluetooth can be used on iOS to communicate with Bluetooth low energy devices using the GATT profile.